# node fs read file from given URL or GCS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filereader, fs

When run bellow code it's give error, Reading file from directory working perfect but when pass url it's give file not found error. I've check fs.statSync accept url.

```
const stat = fs.statSync('http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4');


Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because its hosted on a web-server, you need to send a HTTP GET to fetch it locally.

Install the [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) package and issue a HTTP GET request to fetch the remote resource from the web-server.

```
npm install --save axios
```

---

Here's a program of the general idea

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const writeFilePromise = promisify(fs.writeFile);

(async () => {
  const url = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  if (response.data) {
    await writeFilePromise('small.mp4', response.data);
  }
})();
```

Comment: The `request()` package has been deprecated and it's not promise-based.  It is not recommended for new projects or new users.  There is a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

Comment: Okay Kunal, But I don't want to download video on my local, I just want to read video file from GSC, like file seek

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated my answer to make use of the `axios` library

Comment: @MauryaShubham you will get the video buffer in `response.data` you can do whatever you want with it

Answer (score 1):

`fs.statSync()` can take a URL, but ONLY if that URL is a `file://` URL.

It is not clear what you would want to do if the argument was actually an `http://` URL.  You could check to see if it was not a file URL and then attempt to fetch the contents of the URL to see if it exists using a library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

But, fetching data from another server with http will not be synchronous so you will have to change the design of your function to return a promise instead of a synchronous API.